# C# SMTP Mail Error 5.5.1 Only In Debugger

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail

I'm getting the following error when trying to send an email from my C# application, but only when I'm running it in the Visual Studio IDE

```
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required
```

If I build my application and install it I do not get this error.  I've read through a bunch of similar questions and I've checked all the obvious things, but no existing answer addresses this.

```
System.Net.Mail SmtpClient and MailMessage
.NET Framework 4.5

Host: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 587
EnableSsl: true
UseDefaultCredentials: false
```

I know my email credentials are accurate, it's the same ones I use once the application is installed.  Something about it trying to send an email from the debugger throws an authentication error.

I'm also pretty sure this used to work.  I don't know when it started to fail, and I was too lazy to look into it at the time, but it's growing more and more frustrating.  Perhaps I took an update to either Windows or VS that caused it, I don't know.

### UPDATE

I wanted to clarify since I've done some more testing.  This problem also seems to be related specifically to the app in question.  In order to do some testing I created a simple test app that used my same library for email reporting and it works fine in debugger.  I have even copied the actual methods from my application into my test app and they work.  So there **must** be something in the app settings that is causing this, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Is your SSL certificate real one (bought one) or unreal one generated via Visual Studio? Probably server is checking if this is real certificate.

Comment: I'm not sure how that applies here.  I am using all "real" services for the app's communication with the outside world, and none of this relies on my own SSL cert.  And why would it matter in which context I'm executing my application (debugger vs. installed), even if it were related to that?

Comment: As it turns out I seem to be having mixed results with this.  I was able to get it to work briefly in the Debugger with a test app, but never with my real one.  And now, even in the installed version, my app is unable to send any emails, despite my credentials and settings being fine.

Comment: OK, I figured out why things that had been working stopped.  Apparently, the order in which you set the parameters of the MailClient matters.  You need to set the `UseDefaultCredentials` to `false` **BEFORE** you set the `Credentials`.  Either that or this is a red herring, but it started working immediately after fixing that.  My original problem is still an issue, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this and I wanted to share my experience with the world in case this helps anyone else.  I don't know the actual cause of these errors, but I was able to resolve it by poking around and tweaking the project settings of the application.  At first I thought perhaps I had conflicting GUIDs that were causing a spam filter to go off, so I starting going through the project settings of the app.  While I was there I realized that I didn't actually have a GUID configured for this application and much of the publisher details were all the defaults.  I copied the GUID from my ISTool project I use for building it to an installer and I filled out the other important details in the project settings.  This caused my settings file to get re-created, so I had to re-configure my app settings, but once that was done email worked.  I don't know if this was a safety mechanism to prevent email spamming from hastily thrown together projects or maybe it was blackballed for not having a GUID.  Whatever the reason, it seems that accurately filling out the project info makes a difference.

Hope this helps someone else someday :)